# How to change the datetime in a function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

The original code was shown below.

```
def fn(row):
    d1 = row.sampletime
    d2 = d1 + pd.Timedelta(nDays - 1, 'D')
    return pd.Series(df2.loc[d1:d2].values.reshape((1, -1),
        order='F').squeeze(), index=cols) 
df1 = df1.join(df1.apply(fn, axis=1))
df1
```

I want to change the date `sampletime` to 3 days earlier so I added 2 more lines of code as below:

```
def fn(row):
    m = datetime.timedelta(days = 3)               #new line 
    df1['sampletime'] = df1['sampletime'] - m       #new line

    d1 = row.sampletime
    d2 = d1 + pd.Timedelta(nDays - 1, 'D')
    return pd.Series(df2.loc[d1:d2].values.reshape((1, -1),
        order='F').squeeze(), index=cols) 
df1 = df1.join(df1.apply(fn, axis=1))
df1
```

I received the error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['maxtemp1', 'maxtemp2', 'maxtemp3', 'mintemp1', 'mintemp2', 'mintemp3', 'rainfall1', 'rainfall2', 'rainfall3', 'wind1', 'wind2', 'wind3', 'day_week1', 'day_week2', 'day_week3'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error when there are no common columns in the dataframes. 
Here are the parameters for `pandas.join()`:

`DataFrame.join(self, other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='', sort=False)`

To fix the problem, you need to specify a `lsuffix` and `rsuffix` attribute when you call the function.